# Loading my rails codebase in dev mode is taking ages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

One of my rails apps is a rails 2.2 app with a large codebase.  All of a sudden, it seems to be incredibly slow in dev mode.  This is specifically due to the

`config.cache_classes = false`

option in `config/environments/development.rb` - when i set this to true, then it goes back to normal.  I'd expect the lack of caching to slow it down, but the amount of slowdown i'm seeing is ridiculous: sometimes there will be a 30 second wait before anything starts happening in the log!  Once i see stuff starting to happen in the log file then the page building proceeds as normal.  I think this just started happening recently but i don't know what i could have done to trigger it.

Does anyone know how i could investigate this problem?  All i have to go on now is a 30 second period of nothing happening in the log file.

grateful for any pointers - max

EDIT - just noticed, that when i shut down mongrel_rails (which i use to run the app in dev mode) i get this message:
`Mon Jul 25 16:28:06 +0100 2011: Reaping 5 threads for slow workers because of 'shutdown'`

This might explain the crazy slowdown, but i don't know why there would be 5 threads running.

EDIT2 - this app is running in a ruby 1.8.6 rvm, but switching back to the system ruby (also 1.8.6) didn't help.

EDIT3 - just did an experiment and a `reload!` in my console takes 28 seconds.  So that's definitely the problem.  I just don't understand why it's taking so long.

Comment: for Rails3 only: https://github.com/paneq/active_reload

Comment: Have you recently switched from ruby 1.8 to 1.9?

Comment: @house9 - no, it's a ruby 1.8.6 environment, loaded via RVM.  I wondered if it was caused by the switch to rvm, which i just made recently for this app, but switching rvm back to system and starting the app again didn't make any difference.

Comment: @apneadiving - it (active_reload) is not so much rails 3-dependent as ruby > 1.8.6 dependent by the looks of things.  I tried installing it and got a buffer overflow error.  Upgrading ruby for this app isn't an option right now, sadly.

Comment: any reason to still use **mongrel** on development?

Comment: I'd suggest to you to tune Ruby GC also: https://gist.github.com/865706 because it can reduce time to load/initialize 2x

Comment: @mikhailov - not really, just habit. What would you recommend?

Comment: @mikhailov - in case you're going to say webrick, it's totally broken with this app - it gives up trying to send the page resources, i have to hard refresh a page every time to get the stylesheets!

Comment: As I know, webrick written on Ruby, but passenger, mongrel and unicorn based on cpp. About hard refresh a page - you can to turn off any cache for assets in headers

Comment: anyway, did you try to tune GC?

Comment: @mikhailov - not yet.  I tried setting up an nginx server to proxy to mongrel but it's not helped :/

Answer (score 1):

I found what was causing it, and it's quite surprising.

**SHORT VERSION OF ANSWER:**

The path to my app had gotten very long, and this making a regex somewhere take a long time to test a string containing that filepath.

**LONG VERSION OF ANSWER:**

One mad debugging quest* later i found the offending line:  it's in `lib/localization.rb`, line 56:

```
  filename =~ /(([a-z]+_?)+)\.yaml$/
```

It runs this line twice for me, once for each yaml file in the `lang` folder.  What's really nuts is that the values for 'filename' are

`"/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource_container/e_learning_resource/lang/en.yaml"`

and

`"/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource_container/e_learning_resource/lang/localizations.yaml"`

and, if i run the regex against this in my console, i get a massive delay there as well.  So, the problem is testing the regex against those particular strings.  I just did some experiments into how long it takes the regex to complete, and you can see that it's doubling in time with each extra letter:  from irb (so nothing to do with my app, just plain irb)

```
ruby-1.8.6-p420 :023 > 10.times do |i|
ruby-1.8.6-p420 :024 >     string = "#{string1}#{"a"*i}#{string2}"
ruby-1.8.6-p420 :025?>     time = Time.now
ruby-1.8.6-p420 :026?>     string =~ /(([a-z]+_?)+)\.yaml$/
ruby-1.8.6-p420 :027?>     puts "#{string} -> #{Time.now - time}s"
ruby-1.8.6-p420 :028?>   end
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_/lang/en.yaml -> 0.133935s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_a/lang/en.yaml -> 0.149782s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aa/lang/en.yaml -> 0.198117s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaa/lang/en.yaml -> 0.316208s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaaa/lang/en.yaml -> 0.501882s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaaaa/lang/en.yaml -> 0.896808s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaaaaa/lang/en.yaml -> 1.707035s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaaaaaa/lang/en.yaml -> 3.322242s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaaaaaaa/lang/en.yaml -> 6.613822s
/home/max/work/rails_apps/e_learning_resource/e_learning_resource_aaaaaaaaa/lang/en.yaml -> 13.399231s
```

So, the regex is starting to really struggle with the string.  If i change the regex so that it's

`/([a-z]+_?)\.yaml$/`

instead of

`/(([a-z]+_?)+)\.yaml$/`

, ie removing the ( +) around the inner brackets, then it's fine: super fast.

Adding to the mystery, in localization.rb this offending line is useless!  Here's the whole block containing this line:

```
Dir[RAILS_ROOT + '/lang/*.yaml'].each do |filename|
  filename =~ /(([a-z]+_?)+)\.yaml$/
  hash = YAML::load(File.read(filename))
  file_charset = hash['file_charset'] || 'ascii'
  lang = $1

  # convert string keys to symbols
  symbol_hash = Hash.new
  Iconv.open(CONFIG[:web_charset], file_charset) do |i|
    hash.each do |key, value|
      symbol_hash[key.to_sym] = i.iconv(value)
      if key =~ /^active_record_errors_(.*)/
        I18n.t("activerecord.errors.messages")[$1.to_sym] =
          symbol_hash[key.to_sym]
      end
    end
  end
```

The regex on line 2 here tests the string but doesn't do anything with the result.  Ie, it's *not* saying

```
if filename =~ etc
   ...do something
```

it just tests it for no apparent reason.  So, we've got a regex that blows up with long strings being used for no reason whatsoever.  DOUBLE FAIL.  This is probably an old version of this module, i don't even know how it got into our codebase to be honest.  Off to git to make a pull request for my fixed version (which just deletes that line).

*in case anyone's wondering what my mad debugging quest consisted of, i did the following to add a debug line to the start and end of every rb file in my app.

```
#get every rb file in the working folder
old_filecount = nil
files = []
fstring = "*/"
count = 0
folder = "./"
while old_filecount != files.size
  old_filecount = files.size
  files += Dir[File.join(folder,fstring*count, "*.rb")]
  count += 1
end  
#spam debugging into start and end of every file
files.each do |file|
  `sed '1i\\\nputs \"#\{Time.now} - #\{__FILE__}:#\{__LINE__}\"\' #{file} > tmp.txt;mv tmp.txt #{file}`
  `echo \";puts \\\"#\{Time.now} - #\{__FILE__}:#\{__LINE__}\\\"\" >> #{file}`
end
```

hacky eh.

Comment: That line with regex does something. Matching a regex sets global variables $1,$2 and so on. The variable $1 is assigned to `lang` later. However, using global variables in this way is a very bad programming practice. It looks like 'they' assumed that YAML::load and File.read do not use regexen and never will.

Comment: Ahh....right.  I agree that it's bad coding, not just because the use of globals is discouraged, but also because it's really not obvious at all what's going on.  The funny thing is that i can't find out where that Localization module even came from - my colleague who was the only engineer on the app at the time doesn't remember adding it.  My guess is that it was part of rails at the time when we made our app (it's a rails 2.2.2 app) but i'd have thought that would have made it easier to find on the internets.